# Doubt about probability

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with uniform distribution at $\{0, 1, 2,..., 99\}$. Calculate the probabilities:

(b) $P(2.6<X<12.2)$

My question for this exercise is that $P(2.6<X<12.2)=P(3\leq X\leq12)$ or $P(2.6< X< 12.2)=P(2\leq X\leq 12).$

Comment: Well, ask yourself: If $X=2$, then is $X > 2.6$ or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: Perhaps the exercise would like you to consider using a continuous approximation to the discrete distribution?